# The meaning of "大好きなこのアリアカンパニーで無理に行き先を決めずゆっくり行こう” and to who it is said

Tags: meaning

This is the first line of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNI7hRPT2z8

My problem is trying to understand what is trying to be conveyed. The sentence can be broken into two parts:

大好きなこのアリアカンパニーで and for simplicity we will cut this to このアリアカンパニーで　as it doesn't change the focus of my question as 大好きな informs us of the speakers feelings of the company.

無理に行き先を決めずゆっくり行こう: 
"volitional" form here is used as an invitation to the listener(We who are watching the advert). Or at least I thought it was speaking to us until later on. Starting at 0:43 it appears that the same person who said that initial line is talking to a potential new recruit for the company, which made me think that the line was directed towards this new person instead, although this would to me seem rather strange to do it like this. Can anyone clarify for me who is it that is being spoken to and a very brief contextual translation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She is clearly talking to herself and to be completely honest, my Japanese brain would not take any other interpretations.

The phrase 「[大好]{だいす}きな」 already gives us an important clue right from the beginning.  Who else besides the redhead herself do we know for sure likes アリアカンパニー so much that they plan on spending multiple years with it?  Certainly, not you the viewers or the possible new recruit.

Expressing "I shall ~~~~." is one important function of the volitional.

"I shall move on slowly without forcing myself to decide on my destination with this Aria Company that I love so much "

Comment: That is a very good point, which makes so much sense after I read it.

Comment: @instinctiv: Don't forget to upvote. :-)